# Change height of panel form javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, panel

Using JS Can get the height of an asp.net panel

```
var test1 = $$('ViewFeatureProperties')[0].offsetHeight;

if (test1<500)
{
//change height of panel to 275
$$('ViewFeatureProperties')[0].offsetHeight = 275px;
}
```

could get the value in test1, but wouldnt update to 275 if test1<500, any advice? ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `offsetHeight` property is read only, use `height` instead.

Your first line of code and `if` statement are, at least syntactically, correct examples of how to use it. To set it change your code to read:

```
$$('ViewFeatureProperties')[0].style.height= '275px';
```

Notice I've also wrapped my value with `'` so that I'm assigning it a string.

Alternative:

Since you're using jQuery it seems, you can use jQuery to set the height:

```
$('ViewFeatureProperties').eq(0).height(275);
```

No massive difference, it's just that you now still have your jQuery object if you want to chain more functions.

Comment: missed double $$ on the second example, but yeah worked great. thanks for the help